# Pandas functions too slow - optimise with dict/numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I have ~10 large df's (5mil+ rows each and growing) that I want to perform calculations on. Doing so with raw pandas even on a super fast AWS machine is unbearably slow. Most functions I need are basic so I'm thinking it would be possible to export from pandas to a dict(?), run my calculations then send it back to a df?

The original df is simply a price and size capture of trades as per below (millions of lines as mentioned).

```
                            size      price
time        
2018-05-18 12:05:11.521 -0.026600   8100.000000
2018-05-18 12:05:11.674 -0.115616   8100.000000
2018-05-18 12:05:11.677 -0.026611   8100.000000
2018-05-18 12:05:11.678 -0.074000   8098.400000
2018-05-18 12:05:11.680 -0.783772   8096.600000
2018-05-18 12:05:11.807 -1.000000   8096.600000
2018-05-18 12:05:12.024 -0.100600   8096.600000
2018-05-18 12:05:12.198 -0.899400   8096.600000
2018-05-18 12:05:12.199 -1.600600   8095.100000
2018-05-18 12:05:14.949 1.000000    8092.600000
2018-05-18 12:05:14.951 0.258350    8092.600000
2018-05-18 12:05:30.191 -0.017330   8092.500000
2018-05-18 12:05:30.192 -0.161670   8088.300000
2018-05-18 12:05:30.712 -0.002000   8088.300000
2018-05-18 12:05:30.773 -0.002000   8088.300000
2018-05-18 12:05:34.688 0.003328    8088.400000
```

Now I want to apply the following (which acts as an aggregation of the millions of rows to 5 second windows) :

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5S')).apply(tick_features).shift()[1:]
```

where `tick_features()` is:

```
def tick_features(x):
    if not x.empty:
        open = x['price'].iloc[0]
        close = x['price'].iloc[-1]
    else:
        open = np.nan
        close = np.nan
    high = x['price'].max()
    low = x['price'].min()
    volume = np.abs(x['size']).sum()
    buy_volume = x['size'][x['size'] > 0].sum()
    sell_volume = np.abs(x['size'][x['size'] < 0].sum())
    pct_buy_volume = (buy_volume) / ((buy_volume) + (sell_volume))
    pct_sell_volume = (sell_volume) / ((buy_volume) + (sell_volume))
    num_trades = x['size'].count()
    num_buy_trades = (x['size'] > 0).sum()
    num_sell_trades = (x['size'] < 0).sum()
    pct_buy_trades = (x['size'] > 0).mean() * 100
    pct_sell_trades = (x['size'] < 0).mean() * 100

    return pd.Series([open,high,low,close,volume,buy_volume,sell_volume,pct_buy_volume,pct_sell_volume,
                      num_trades,num_buy_trades,num_sell_trades,pct_buy_trades,pct_sell_trades], 
                     index=['open','high','low','close','volume','buy_volume','sell_volume','pct_buy_volume','pct_sell_volume',
                            'num_trades','num_buy_trades','num_sell_trades','pct_buy_trades','pct_sell_trades'])
```

This type of optimization is out of my league so any explanation if this is even feasible to begin with if much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is slow because there are so many groups and for every group, Pandas need to create a DataFrame object and pass it to `tick_features()`, the loop is executed in Python.

To speedup the calculation, you can call aggregation methods that executed in Cython loop:

Prepare some dummy data first:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range("2018-05-01", "2018-06-02", freq="0.1S")
x = np.random.randn(idx.shape[0], 2)

df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=idx, columns=["size", "price"])
```

add extra columns to it, the calculation is fast, if you have enough memory:

```
df["time"] = df.index
df["volume"] = df["size"].abs()
df["buy_volume"] = np.clip(df["size"], 0, np.inf)
df["sell_volume"] = np.clip(df["size"], -np.inf, 0)
df["buy_trade"] = df["size"] > 0
df["sell_trade"] = df["size"] < 0
```

then group the DataFrame object first, and call aggregation methods:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="5s"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
    open = g["time"].first(),
    close = g["time"].last(),
    high = g["price"].max(),
    low = g["price"].min(),
    volume = g["volume"].sum(),
    buy_volume = g["buy_volume"].sum(),
    sell_volume = -g["sell_volume"].sum(),
    num_trades = g["size"].count(),
    buy_trade = g["buy_trade"].sum(),
    sell_trade = g["sell_trade"].sum(),
    pct_buy_trades  = g["buy_trade"].mean() * 100,
    pct_sell_trades = g["sell_trade"].mean() * 100,
    )
)

d = df2.eval("buy_volume + sell_volume")
df2["pct_buy_volume"] = df2.eval("buy_volume / @d")
df2["pct_sell_volume"] = df2.eval("sell_volume / @d")
```

Comment: Phenomenal, that was blazingly fast. Any good resources on learning these interactions or mostly through experience? Thanks.

Comment: here is some speed comparison: for loop in numba or cython > numpy vectorize calculation > for loop with list, dict  > for loop with numpy array > for loop with DataFrame.  Here is the document about cython optimized aggregation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions