# pd.Grouper function - failing on one of many df's

Tags: python, pandas, debugging

I am trying to iterate over multiple separate df's with `pd.Grouper` as the answer  [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672970/pandas-functions-too-slow-optimise-with-dict-numpy)

Now, **this works** for 7 out of my 8 df's and only takes a few seconds. However one of them - not even the largest gets caught up and hangs and eventually dies with a memory error and I have no idea why as the df's are almost identical.

The trouble block of code is below:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="5s"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
    open = g["price"].first(),
    close = g["price"].last(),
    high = g["price"].max(),
    low = g["price"].min(),
    volume = g["volume"].sum(),
    buy_volume = g["buy_volume"].sum(),
    sell_volume = -g["sell_volume"].sum(),
    num_trades = g["size"].count(),
    num_buy_trades = g["buy_trade"].sum(),
    num_sell_trades = g["sell_trade"].sum(),
    pct_buy_trades  = g["buy_trade"].mean() * 100,
    pct_sell_trades = g["sell_trade"].mean() * 100,
    )
)
```

The sample df in question is in the following format:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3589964 entries, 1970-01-01 00:00:01.528000 to 2018-06-03 05:54:02.690000
Data columns (total 8 columns):
price          float64
size           float64
buy_sell       bool
volume         float64
buy_volume     float64
sell_volume    float64
buy_trade      bool
sell_trade     bool
dtypes: bool(3), float64(5)
memory usage: 254.6 MB
```

with 3.5mil entries like below:

```
     price    size     buy_sell    volume   buy_volume  sell_volume buy_trade   sell_trade
T
2018-05-18 12:05:11.407 8097.02 0.007823    False   0.007823    0.007823    0.000000    True    False
2018-05-18 12:05:11.720 8097.02 0.129632    False   0.129632    0.129632    0.000000    True    False
2018-05-18 12:05:12.402 8097.02 0.037028    False   0.037028    0.037028    0.000000    True    False
2018-05-18 12:05:12.786 8097.03 0.307939    False   0.307939    0.307939    0.000000    True    False
2018-05-18 12:05:12.786 8097.02 0.025517    False   0.025517    0.025517    0.000000    True    False
2018-05-18 12:05:12.788 8097.03 0.014835    False   0.014835    0.014835    0.000000    True    False
2018-05-18 12:05:14.226 8097.03 0.006198    False   0.006198    0.006198    0.000000    True    False
2018-05-18 12:05:14.341 8092.00 -0.010989   True    0.010989    0.000000    -0.010989   False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:15.307 8092.00 -0.000011   True    0.000011    0.000000    -0.000011   False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:15.307 8091.99 -0.019989   True    0.019989    0.000000    -0.019989   False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:15.387 8091.99 -0.007340   True    0.007340    0.000000    -0.007340   False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:15.603 8091.99 -0.002440   True    0.002440    0.000000    -0.002440   False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:15.679 8090.01 -0.098909   True    0.098909    0.000000    -0.098909   False   True
```

This is another df that works completely fine and completes in a few seconds:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1952985 entries, 2018-05-18 12:05:11.791000 to 2018-06-03 05:53:57
Data columns (total 8 columns):
price          float64
side           object
size           int64
volume         int64
buy_volume     float64
sell_volume    float64
buy_trade      bool
sell_trade     bool
dtypes: bool(2), float64(3), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 188.0+ MB

    price   side    size    volume  buy_volume  sell_volume buy_trade   sell_trade
timestamp                               
2018-05-18 12:05:11.791 8112.0  Sell    -4085   4085    0.0 -4085.0 False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:11.811 8111.5  Sell    -598    598 0.0 -598.0  False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:11.849 8111.5  Sell    -3000   3000    0.0 -3000.0 False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:11.876 8111.5  Sell    -1300   1300    0.0 -1300.0 False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:11.949 8111.5  Sell    -3408   3408    0.0 -3408.0 False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:12.476 8111.5  Sell    -50000  50000   0.0 -50000.0    False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:12.523 8111.5  Sell    -2500   2500    0.0 -2500.0 False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:12.698 8111.5  Sell    -8000   8000    0.0 -8000.0 False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:12.722 8111.5  Sell    -8000   8000    0.0 -8000.0 False   True
2018-05-18 12:05:12.809 8111.5  Sell    -815    815 0.0 -815.0  False   True
```

- I don't know why this is happening.. how do I even begin to debug it?

I've been waiting to copy the error message, but it's been stuck for 50 minutes.

Thanks for any help, this has been doing my head in!

Comment: Hard to know without see completely data, but maybe character problem of `DataetimeIndex` - `groupby` need create many small `5s` groups.

Comment: did a `sort_index()` and found a single rogue row where date that was `1970-1-1` an error from parsing epoch time, removed it and now it's fixed! Surprised that single date caused so much grief, must have checked every 5s from there. Nice intuition!

Comment: It was my first idea, but because seen `2018-05-18 12:05:11.791000 to 2018-06-03 05:53:57` I think datetimeindex is lareday sorted :)

Comment: yeah it was but i did it again to make sure, the trouble df in the post has `DatetimeIndex: 3589964 entries, 1970-01-01 00:00:01.528000 to 2018-06-03 05:54:02.690000`. Feel free to make an answer so I can award :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea is sorting `index` by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

If still problem with performance, there should be data character problem of `DataetimeIndex` - `groupby` create many small `5s` groups.

EDIT:

After [double check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713595/pd-grouper-function-failing-on-one-of-many-dfs?noredirect=1#comment88439154_50713595) `DatetimIndex` is:

```
DatetimeIndex: 3589964 entries, 1970-01-01 00:00:01.528000 to 2018-06-03 05:54:02.690000
```

so here is huge amount af groups what is reason of bad performance.